# Responsive Nav Menu Using Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I was attempting to build a responsive `nav` using `flexbox`.  When the screen is smaller than 744px, I wanted a toggle button to appear, the main nav to have a `max-height` of 0, and then on click, have the nav display in block.  Fairly typical stuff.

However, I'm used to doing this just with floats and I'm running into several problems:

1. I don't understand how to drop the UL below the nav without pushing the nav logo and toggle up;
2. The UL with the LI doesn't seem to be responding to the max-height trick.

If anyone can provide some assistance or point me in the direction of tutorial that would be great.

```css
* {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: 'open-sans', 'sans-serif';
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #444;
}

.navText {
    font-size: 14px;
}

nav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}

.nav-fixedWidth {
    //border: 1px solid;
    min-height: 120px;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.mainNav {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
}

.mainNav li {
    margin-right: 60px;
    padding: 10px;
    //border: 1px solid;
}

.mainNav li:nth-child(5){ 
    margin-right: 10px;
}


.mainNav li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #444;
    display: block;
}

.mainNav li a:hover {
    color: #9d9d9d;
}

.logo {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.toggle {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    display: none;
}




@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    
    .nav-fixedWidth
    {
        width: 95vw;
    }
    
}

@media screen and (max-width: 744px) {
    
    .nav-fixedWidth
    {
        flex-wrap:wrap;
    }
    
    .toggle
    {
        display: block;
    }
    

}
```

```html
        <nav>
            <div class="nav-fixedWidth">
                <div class="logo"></div>
                <div class="toggle"></div>
                <ul class="mainNav">
                    <li class="navText"><a href="#webinars">Webinars</a></li>
                    <li class="navText"><a href="#eBooks">e-Books</a></li>
                    <li class="navText"><a href="#Blog">Blog</a></li>
                    <li class="navText"><a href="#eCourse">e-Course</a></li>
                    <li class="navText"><a href="#">Search</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be a bit late for your particular need, but you might want to take a look at this solution by Chris Coiyer

https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/GJRXYE

```
html {
  background: #666;
}

body {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: white;
}

.nav {
  position: relative;
  ul {
    display: flex;
    height: 3rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    width: 80%;
  }
  li {
    a {
      display: block;
      padding: 1rem 0.5rem;
      text-decoration: none;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
  }
  &.open {
    ul {
      height: auto;
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
.x {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.75rem;
  right: 0.75rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

This solution does require a small amount of JavaScript to toggle the menu.

Hope it helps :-)